# Potential attack

Tags: myetherwallet, private-key, encryption, encoding

I have two  computers, one of them is  airgapped.

I had also  two MEW  private key, stored in the  airgapped computer, I made   a lot  of transaction from the  first private key  to the second one.

I have made several transactions using MEW OFFLINE  and  recording  several signed transactions and  addresses on the computer  with Internet (but not the private keys)

So on my computer  with internet  has been  recorded  addresses  in which to send  the coins  TO  and  FROM  +  all the signed transactions  made time after time

all recorded in the  on line computer

Remember this part because it's important.

Well, one  day I decide  to use  MEW ONLINE  ONLINE so I  write in plane  text  one  of my two private keys  in the on line pc   and  I drain the  wallet  sending the coins  to  the second  Myethereumwallet I had  (remember  at the start of this  post I told you I had two  MEW wallets?)

Well,    a potencial attacker could have recorded  in the on line computer  thes  things:

1)  addresses of the two wallets

2)  all the signed transactions made  between these  two wallets

3)  One  of the  two private key used only one time on line to drain the  first  MEW  wallet  and to transfer the coins to the second  MEW wallet

With  all those  informations  could an attakker build up a pattern to decrypt the second  private  key?

I remember you that  he  could have addresses + one private key +  all the signed transactions made between  those two wallets

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is no relationship between your two private keys - ie, you didn't pick two that were in sequential order or something, then an attacker can't decrypt your private key based on any of that information.

If the two keys were related in some way, then if they found one they may be able to guess the other.

As for the other information, all transactions and addresses are public, so if it were possible to decrypt a private key from that then anyone's key could be stolen at any time. But don't worry, that's cryptographically impossible.

You may want to read up on [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

Comment: Hello, my two private  key were  related  in some  way,  meaning  that  I have used  them  to send  funds  to each  other  and to other   addresses,   recording  the  signed  transaction of  every tx on the internet  computer.  This  is  the relationship  between  the two keys  And  one of those  two keys  is public  accessible for  an hacker, because I written  it  on the  PC used  for ON LINe  transaction. I wonder if they can spot the other  key based  on the first key and  the signed transactions+ addresses .

Comment: No they can't. It doesn't matter what transactions have gone between the two, that's all a matter of public record anyway - every full node has a copy of every transaction ever made. By related I meant if your private keys were not chosen at random, but rather were numbers that followed a pattern or something. but that's a terrible idea regardless of what setup you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much, and  sorry  for  all my concern.  So the  fact that  the attacker has ONE  of the two MEW private keys +  both public MEW addresses + previous signed transactions  between  the  two MEW wallets  won't  help  him in some way  to  recover the private key of the second  MyEthereum Wallet?

Comment: No, it's no different to how if you and me send ETH to eachother, there's no way for you to work out my private key just by looking at the transactions.

Comment: Thank you so much... but remember that  an attacker  could  have  also  one  of the  two private keys used  to  previously send  funds  between the  two MyEtherwallet addresses .

Comment: it doesnt matter. you can't work out a private key from another private key or from addresses or any other public information. if you could, the whole system would fail.